# Android Facebook SDk; can i get user cover image using his facebook id?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

i have some ids of users of facebook , can i get the cover image of each user using his id . i could get the profile image through this method

```
http://graph.facebook.com/+"user_id"+/picture?type=large
```

but i dont know how to get their cover images

i could to get my own cover photo by:

```
 GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                    // Insert your code here
                    loadTopUser();
                }
            });

    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("fields", "cover");
    request.setParameters(parameters);
    request.executeAsync();
```

what the change should i do in this request to get friends cover photo  if there is no static url like ,
 http://graph.facebook.com/+"user_id"+/picture?type=large  to get the cover ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find the answer

You should make sure that **access token is not null** and you already logged in by facebook so as not to access tokes is null

String id= 1234567910111213;

```
new GraphRequest(
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            "/+id+?fields=cover",
            null,
            HttpMethod.GET,
            new GraphRequest.Callback()
            {
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject();
                        if(jsonObject==null) 
                            return;
                        JSONObject JOSource = jsonObject.getJSONObject("cover");
                        String coverPhoto = JOSource.getString("source");

                    }
                    catch (JSONException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
    ).executeAsync();
```